# Brightness and Contrast for a canvas image with javascript

Tags: javascript, image, canvas, brightness, contrast

I have an image in a tag

```
var img = new Image();
ctx.drawImage(img,0,0,img.width,img.height);
ecc...
```

How is possible to change the Brightness and Contrast of this image with javascript?

Tnx

Comment: -1: You at least could tell which programming language is your question about

Comment: Added the javascript tag. This way, there are more chances that javascript experts check the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's at least one javascript library I know of which can do this, [Pixastic](http://enotionz.github.io/pixastic-docs/)

Usage might look like this.

```
Pixastic.process(canvas, 'brightness',
    {
        'brightness': 60,
        'contrast': 0.5,
        'leaveDOM': true
    },
    function(img) {
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    }
);
```

The library is kind of intended to work with images within your page and it replaces them with canvas elements which contain the rendered result.

But in the code above I've passed in a canvas element rather than an image and included the 'leaveDOM' property to prevent the pixastic library from swapping your canvas in the DOM for the one it creates.

To display the results I've included the callback function which just does ctx.drawImage to put the contents into your original canvas.

Hope that makes sense.

You can check the documentation for more examples. [Pixastic Documentation](http://enotionz.github.io/pixastic-docs/)

Comment: The Pixastic link at the beginning point to a different page.

Comment: Thank you for this answer, I've updated the links to Pixastic docs.

Comment: Despite mentioning "Use Legacy" in the Pixastic docs, their non-legacy mode doesn't seem to actually implement Photoshop's modern (internally curves-based) adjustment layer.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, fabric.js is the best javascript library for performing this. Check out Fabric JS and how to do image filtering at: http://fabricjs.com/image-filters

Comment: aff, dead link :\

Comment: Updated the broken link

Answer (score -2):

you can try this  , see comment

```
<script type="application/javascript">  

function clickMeEvent(obj)
{
if (obj.style.opacity=="0.9")
    {
    obj.style.opacity="0.7";
    }
else if (obj.style.opacity=="0.7")
    {
    obj.style.opacity="0.5";        
    }
else if (obj.style.opacity=="0.5")
    {
    obj.style.opacity="0.3";        
    }
else if (obj.style.opacity=="0.3")
    {
    obj.style.opacity="0.1";        
    }
else
    {
    obj.style.opacity="0.0";

    }
}

</script>
```

Comment: put this on the top  <html>
<div>
<img style="opacity:0.9;" src="your image location" onclick="clickMeEvent(this)">
</div>

Comment: You can't be serious.

Answer (score -3):

You can try this (c# code):

```
 Bitmap originalImage;
 Bitmap adjustedImage;
 double brightness = 1.0f; // no change in brightness
 double constrast = 2.0f; // twice the contrast
 double gamma = 1.0f; // no change in gamma

 float adjustedBrightness = brightness - 1.0f;
 float[][] ptsArray ={
                new float[] {contrast, 0, 0, 0, 0}, // scale red
                new float[] {0, contrast, 0, 0, 0}, // scale green
                new float[] {0, 0, contrast, 0, 0}, // scale blue
                new float[] {0, 0, 0, 1.0f, 0}, // don't scale alpha
                new float[] {adjustedBrightness, adjustedBrightness, adjustedBrightness, 0, 1}};

 imageAttributes = new ImageAttributes();
 imageAttributes.ClearColorMatrix();
 imageAttributes.SetColorMatrix(new ColorMatrix(ptsArray), ColorMatrixFlag.Default, ColorAdjustType.Bitmap);
 imageAttributes.SetGamma(gamma, ColorAdjustType.Bitmap);
 Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(adjustedImage);
 g.DrawImage(originalImage, new Rectangle(0,0,adjustedImage.Width,adjustedImage.Height)
            ,0,0,bitImage.Width,bitImage.Height,
 GraphicsUnit.Pixel, imageAttributes);
```

Comment: @PizzaiolaGorgonzola The question originally didn't mention the language.