# how to use brightness and contrast of an image using jquery

Tags: jquery, image, brightness

I have a slider of brightess/contrast for a dynamically images.I am opening the image as i just browse it in input type = file.using jquery.I have slider input type=range .on sliding up increse brightness and on sliding down it will decrease brightness.

pls tell me how can to do this.

Comment: Perhaps you're using some plugin?

Answer (score 0):

For this you can use the Pixastic library of javascript.

Here is the link: http://www.pixastic.com/

Here are so many examples in pixastic documentation page: http://www.pixastic.com/lib/docs/

Comment: my friend have already used this but its not working fine.please follow the links  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16538706/pixastic-process-function-is-not-working-repeatedly

Comment: @abdulquadir: follow this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3905572/brightness-and-contrast-for-a-canvas-image-with-javascript?rq=1